# Problems while trying to create a new id column based on three criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with conversations and timestamps like this:

```
timestamp   userID  textBlob    new_id
2018-10-05 23:07:02 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:07:13 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:07:23 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:07:36 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:08:02 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:09:16 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:09:21 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:09:39 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:09:47 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:10:01 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:10:11 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:10:23 01  restart             
2018-10-05 23:10:59 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-05 23:11:03 01  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 23:11:32 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 23:12:58 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 23:13:16 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 23:14:04 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:38:36 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:38:42 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:38:52 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:38:57 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:39:10 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:39:27 02  Restart             
2018-10-08 03:40:47 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:40:54 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:41:02 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:41:12 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:41:32 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:41:39 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:42:20 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:44:58 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:45:54 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 03:46:06 02  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:06:42 03  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:06:53 03  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:08:49 03  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:08:58 03  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:58:18 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:58:26 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:58:37 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 05:58:58 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:00:31 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:01:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:01:14 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:02:03 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:02:03 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:06:03 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 06:10:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 09:07:03 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-08 09:09:03 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-09 10:01:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-09 10:02:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-09 10:03:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-09 10:09:00 04  a large text blob...
2018-10-09 10:09:00 05  a large text blob...
```

At the moment I would like to identify with an id the conversations inside the dataframe. The problem is that a user can have several conversations (i.e. an `userID` can have multiple `textBlob` associated). Thus, I would like to add a `new_id` in order to be able to identify the conversations inside the above dataframe.

For this, I would like to create a `new_id` column based on three criteria:

1. 10 minutes periods
2. the occurrence of a keyword
3. when a user doesnt have more textblobs

The expected output looks like this `(*)`:

```
timestamp   userID  textBlob    new_id
2018-10-05 23:07:02 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:07:13 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:07:23 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:07:36 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:08:02 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:09:16 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:09:21 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:09:39 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:09:47 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:10:01 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:10:11 01  a large text blob...    001
2018-10-05 23:10:23 01  restart                 001   ---- (The word restart appeared so a new id is created ↓)
2018-10-05 23:10:59 01  a large text blob...    002
2018-10-05 23:11:03 01  a large text blob...    002
2018-10-08 23:11:32 02  a large text blob...    002
2018-10-08 23:12:58 02  a large text blob...    002
2018-10-08 23:13:16 02  a large text blob...    002
2018-10-08 23:14:04 02  a large text blob...    002   --- (The conversation ends because the 10 minutes time threshold was exceeded)
2018-10-08 03:38:36 02  a large text blob...    003
2018-10-08 03:38:42 02  a large text blob...    003
2018-10-08 03:38:52 02  a large text blob...    003
2018-10-08 03:38:57 02  a large text blob...    003
2018-10-08 03:39:10 02  a large text blob...    003
2018-10-08 03:39:27 02  Restart                 003   ---- (The word restart appeared so a new id is created ↓)
2018-10-08 03:40:47 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:40:54 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:41:02 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:41:12 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:41:32 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:41:39 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:42:20 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:44:58 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:45:54 02  a large text blob...    004
2018-10-08 03:46:06 02  a large text blob...    004     ---- (The 10 minutes threshold is exceeded a new id is assigned ↓)
2018-10-08 05:06:42 03  a large text blob...    005
2018-10-08 05:06:53 03  a large text blob...    005
2018-10-08 05:08:49 03  a large text blob...    005
2018-10-08 05:08:58 03  a large text blob...    005     ---- (no more conversations from user id 03, thus the a new id is assigned)
2018-10-08 05:58:18 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 05:58:26 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 05:58:37 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 05:58:58 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 06:00:31 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 06:01:00 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 06:01:14 04  a large text blob...    006
2018-10-08 06:02:03 04  a large text blob...    006     ---- (The 10 minutes threshold is exceeded a new id is assigned ↓)
2018-10-08 06:02:03 04  a large text blob...    007
2018-10-08 06:06:03 04  a large text blob...    007
2018-10-08 06:10:00 04  a large text blob...    007
2018-10-08 09:07:03 04  a large text blob...    007
2018-10-08 09:09:03 04  a large text blob...    007     ---- (The 10 minutes threshold is exceeded a new id is assigned ↓)
2018-10-09 10:01:00 04  a large text blob...    008
2018-10-09 10:02:00 04  a large text blob...    008
2018-10-09 10:03:00 04  a large text blob...    008
2018-10-09 10:09:00 04  a large text blob...    008     ---- (no more conversations from user id 04, thus the a new id is assigned)
2018-10-09 10:09:00 05  a large text blob...    010
```

So far I tried to:

```
searchfor = ['restart','Restart']
df['keyword_id'] = df['textBlob'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))
```

And

```
dif = df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()
periods = dif > pd.Timedelta('10 min')
times = periods.cumsum().apply(lambda x: x+1)
df['time_id'] = times
```

However, I also need to consider the userID and I end up with several columns. Is there any way of fulfilling the three conditions and getting the expected output `(*)`?

Comment: Should there be a new id assigned between the lines `2018-10-05 23:11:03` and `2018-10-08 03:11:32`, since `userID` changes from `01` to `02`? Also, why does the new ID jump from `005` to `007`?

Comment: Thanks for the help @PeterLeimbigler, no I made a mistake while generating the data.. I fixed it check again

Comment: thanks. There is now a jump from `008` to `010`, and the lines I mentioned above still don't have a userID increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way there. To put it all together, build a boolean mask for each condition, then convert the masks to int and take their cumulative sum:

```
mask1 = df.timestamp.diff() > pd.Timedelta(10, 'm') 
mask2 = df['userID'].diff() != 0
mask3 = df['textBlob'].shift().str.lower() == 'restart'

df['new_id'] = (mask1 | mask2 | mask3).astype(int).cumsum()

# Result:
print(df.to_string(index=False))

timestamp  userID              textBlob  new_id
2018-10-05 23:07:02       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:07:13       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:07:23       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:07:36       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:08:02       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:09:16       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:09:21       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:09:39       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:09:47       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:10:01       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:10:11       1  a_large_text_blob...       1
2018-10-05 23:10:23       1               restart       1
2018-10-05 23:10:59       1  a_large_text_blob...       2
2018-10-05 23:11:03       1  a_large_text_blob...       2
2018-10-08 03:11:32       2  a_large_text_blob...       3
2018-10-08 03:12:58       2  a_large_text_blob...       3
2018-10-08 03:13:16       2  a_large_text_blob...       3
2018-10-08 03:14:04       2  a_large_text_blob...       3
2018-10-08 03:38:36       2  a_large_text_blob...       4
2018-10-08 03:38:42       2  a_large_text_blob...       4
2018-10-08 03:38:52       2  a_large_text_blob...       4
2018-10-08 03:38:57       2  a_large_text_blob...       4
2018-10-08 03:39:10       2  a_large_text_blob...       4
2018-10-08 03:39:27       2               Restart       4
2018-10-08 03:40:47       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:40:54       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:41:02       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:41:12       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:41:32       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:41:39       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:42:20       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:44:58       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:45:54       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 03:46:06       2  a_large_text_blob...       5
2018-10-08 05:06:42       3  a_large_text_blob...       6
2018-10-08 05:06:53       3  a_large_text_blob...       6
2018-10-08 05:08:49       3  a_large_text_blob...       6
2018-10-08 05:08:58       3  a_large_text_blob...       6
2018-10-08 05:58:18       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 05:58:26       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 05:58:37       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 05:58:58       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:00:31       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:01:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:01:14       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:02:03       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:02:03       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:06:03       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 06:10:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       7
2018-10-08 09:07:03       4  a_large_text_blob...       8
2018-10-08 09:09:03       4  a_large_text_blob...       8
2018-10-09 10:01:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       9
2018-10-09 10:02:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       9
2018-10-09 10:03:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       9
2018-10-09 10:09:00       4  a_large_text_blob...       9
2018-10-09 10:09:00       5  a_large_text_blob...      10
```

Comment: @tumbleweed, I've adjusted the `restart` logic, so this output should be what you're looking for. Let me know if I'm still missing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I thought the 10 minutes period should count from the beginning of the conversation, not from the immediate below message, in that case you would need to iterate over the rows like:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
restart = df.textBlob.str.contains('|'.join(['restart','Restart']))
user_change = df.userID == df.userID.shift().fillna(method='bfill')
df['new_id'] = (restart | ~user_change).cumsum()
current_id = 0
new_id_prev = 0
start_time = df.timestamp.iloc[0]

for i, new_id, timestamp in zip(range(len(df)), df.new_id, df.timestamp):
    timedelta = timestamp - start_time

    if new_id != new_id_prev or timedelta > pd.Timedelta(10,unit='m'):
        current_id += 1
        start_time = timestamp

    new_id_prev = new_id    
    df.new_id.iloc[i] = current_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!